# $G_{\delta}$ null dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to construct a $G_{\delta}$ set A which is dense and has Lebesgue-measure $\lambda(A) = 0$. I have thought of taking the points $x_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and building open balls of radius $2^{-i}\epsilon$ around them, then joining them all together in a set $U$ which has measure $\lambda(U) \le 2\epsilon$. $U$ is obviously dense and open (hence $G_{\delta}$) and the measure can get arbitrarily close to $0$, but since it is open it can never be exactly $0$.

I guess that somehow my idea of taking balls around points of $\mathbb{Q}$ is probably the easiest way of doing this, however my approach is not the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Baire category theorem says that if $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $A_n$ are open and dense then $A$ is dense again. So it suffices to choose a sequence of open dense sets whose measure tends to zero, then take their intersection. You have basically found such a sequence: you have $U(\epsilon)$, so take $A_n=U(2^{-n})$ (or whatever other decaying sequence you like).

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the last step with the monotonic sequence!

Answer (score 2):

Another construction: Just look at the interval $[0,1]$ and iterate this process in each interval. Let $A_n$ be the fat cantor set of measure $\displaystyle \frac{n}{n+1}$. Then $A_n^c$ is open and dense. By Baire Category, $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n^c$ is dense. By construction it is $G_\delta$, and it is null, since $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n\right) =1.$

Comment: I think you have a typo, that $0$ at the end should be $1$.

Comment: Oops -- thanks!