# Is there a dense set that is a countable intersection of open sets with measure $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a dense set $A$ that is a countable intersection of open sets, so that $m(A)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

I've been thinking that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a perfect candidate, but it's not a countable intersection of open sets.

Comment: The question is not too clear. What must have measure $0$?

Comment: sorry, is it clearer now?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459121/g-delta-null-dense-set

Comment: thanks. is there a solution without biare's category theorem?

Comment: Can you find an open set of measure $\lt\varepsilon$ that contains $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: The denseness of the intersection of shrinking open covers of the rationals doesn't need Baire Category Theorem; the intersection contains the rationals (snce each set in the cover does) and so it is dense.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a valid answer:

If we look at $\cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} (q-\frac{1}{n},q+\frac{1}{n})$ this is an open set and $\cap_{n\in N} \cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} (q-\frac{1}{n},q+\frac{1}{n}) = \mathbb{Q}$ which has a measure $0$?
is this correct?

Comment: Unfortunately for a fixed $n$, your union is just all of $\mathbb R$, so the countable intersection is also just $\mathbb R$. You can instead (as is suggested in the comments) use a cover like $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (q_n - \epsilon / 2^n , q_n + \epsilon / 2^n )$ which is not all of $\mathbb R$ (it has finite measure) and it is open; then take an intersection over $\epsilon = 1/m \to 0$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm having some technical problems with the intersection: If  $O_m=\cup_n(q_n-\frac{1}{m2^n},q_n+\frac{1}{m2^n})$, Than $m(O_m)\le \sum_n{\epsilon/2^{n-1}}=\epsilon$. but what is the measure of $O=\cap_mO_m$? Is $O_m$ a decreasing sequence in $m$?

Comment: Of course I mean that $\epsilon=\frac{1}{m}$

Comment: Yes, the sets are nested. The intersection of the first N is $O_N$ which has measure at most $1/N$. For nested sets the limit of the measure is the measure of the limit.